# How to shrink the data from multiple columns into one column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

hopefully someone will be able to help me. I need to write a query, which would shrink the data from multiple columns (in my case from columns A:H) into one column.
The original file looks like this:
[image]

I need to shrink the data one by one by rows. I mean, the query has to check the first row and take the data (name), and put it into "a new column" then check the second column and do the same, and continue like this one by one. The table has 170 rows.

I found a query that is shrinking the data from multiple columns into one column but in another order than I need. The query is taking as first all data from a column A and putting it into "a new column", then taking all data from a column B and putting it into "a new column" under the data from the previous column (column A).
This is the query I tried to apply:
[image]

Please could somebody help me with it? I have to admit that I have not use UBound and LBound functions and I am getting pretty lost here. :(

I will be thankful for any advise how to adjust this query.

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Paste your code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I'm first setting your range to an array. I then loop through the array and 'slice' each row using `Application.Index`. It then `Join`s all the content in that row together before `Trim`ming the whitespace left over from either end. This leaves me with the one value in my results array (`tmp`). The code then clears your source data before leaving all your data in one column.

```
Sub CombineColumns()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tmp As Variant, vaCells As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Sheets("DATA").Range("A2:H200")
    vaCells = rng.Value2

    ReDim tmp(LBound(vaCells) To UBound(vaCells))

    For i = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
        tmp(i) = Trim(Join(Application.Index(vaCells, i, 0)))
    Next i

    With rng
        .ClearContents
        .Cells(1).Resize(UBound(tmp)).Value2 = Application.Transpose(tmp)
    End With
End Sub
```

`LBound` returns the lowest position in the array (usually 0 or 1) and `UBound` returns the highest

Comment: This is great! Thank you very very much! I works exactly in a way I need! I really appreciate your help! It saved a lot of time. :) Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this

```
for i = 1 to 170
    for y = 1 to 8
        if worksheets("trainers").cells(i,y).value <> "" then 
            worksheets("output").cells(i,1).value = worksheets("trainers").cells(i,y).value
            exit for
        end if
    next y
next i
```

or on same sheet

```
For i = 1 To 170
Z = 0
    For y = 1 To 8
        If Cells(i, y).Value = "" Then
            Cells(i, y).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            Z = Z + 1
            If Z <= 8 Then y = y - 1
        End If
    Next y
Next i
```